# License required to access User object

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, permissions

I have a requirement to show user list inside the lightning component. Its working fine for all the users except users with "Chatter Only" license. For Chatter-only license, whenever they access that lightning component, they are getting "Insufficient Permission error". I tried removing "With Sharing" keyword from the class which uses SOQL to retrieve users list. But still, I am getting the same error.

If Chatter-only license can't access user object, then please let me know which all licenses can access user object from apex.

Comment: To avoid the license limit, You can create a Wrapper class with the user's attributes that you wan't you.

Comment: @Torsen even if I create a wrapper class, will I be able to get user object data using SOQL. I believe the chatter-only profile user don't have permission to query user records.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, would be counted in as license abuse. SF might charge you more for it. Ideal solution would be to move them to standard SF license as they need access to SF data, not just chatter

Comment: put the SOQL in a without sharing class